# Track the number of requests per client per api in Spring Boot using Micrometer

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-cloudwatch, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am using AWS Cloudwatch to monitor my application. I want to track the number of requests I receive per client per API. I have micrometer configured for other metrics. How do I track this metric using micrometer?

For reference, I have a finite set of clients using my service. I can make a manual `Counter` for each of them. But is there a way to automate this since I don't want to manually create a counter every time a new client is added. Or is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create extra `Counter`s since Spring Boot already creates a `Timer` for your requests (you should see `http.server.requests` in CloudWatch). A `Timer` always contains a count, the rule of thumb is Never Count something that you can Time.

Spring Boot already tags your `Timer`s with the API path so the problem is how to tag every timer with the client information. For this Spring Boot offers you, [WebMvcTagsContributor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcTagsContributor.html) and [WebFluxTagsContributor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/web/reactive/server/WebFluxTagsContributor.html) for MVC and for WebFlux app. You implement one of these interfaces (depending if you use MVC of WebFlux) create a `@Bean` from it and Spring Boot will auto-configure it for you so that your tags will be enhanced with whatever data you want.

Implementation tip: try to avoid adding raw user input to your tags because that can lead to potentially having hight cardinality data. Try to map your user input to distinct values and fall back to invalid/unknown/etc. if you get a non matching one.

Comment: That seems interesting. Is it possible for you to provide a sample implementation of the concept using WebMvcTagsContributor?